# how to return assosciative arrays in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

hello want to know how are associative arrays passed as return values

code:

```
function abc()
begin
int value[string][string];
value = def();
end

function int def()
begin
int new_value[string][string];
//logic to populate the array
return new_value;
end
```

I am seeing the following error:
The type of target is int.
While, the type of source is int$[string][string].

How to handle this and pass the assosciative array seamlessly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a function to return an aggregate type, you need to declare a `typedef` first, then use that as the return value.

```
typedef int AA_t[string][string];
function AA_t def();
  AA_t new_value; 
  //logic to populate the array
  return new_value;
endfunction
```

Once you have the `typedef` you might as well use it everywhere.

Comment: how to get the size of a multidimensional array in system verilog. Lets say i define the array as int array_name[string][string][string] . I want to know if the array is null or not  and even get the number of elements the array contains.

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question for better formatting and to help others search for similar issues. SystemVerilog has arrays of arrays, not really multidimensional arrays, so you cannot use the `size` function to get the size of each dimension. You will have to use `foreach (array_name[I,j,k]) ...` to iterate through the array.